# How to create a copy of a defined table in Excel which auto-updates when changes to the original table are made?

Tags: excel

I have defined a table in MS Excel and want an exact copy of this table on another worksheet which updates itself when changes are made on the original table. For instance, if one inserts a new line at the end of the original table, excel auto-expands this table - this should also be reflected on the table copy.
Is this possible without VBA?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if this very practical, but you could go to Sheet2 and just put `=Sheet1!A1` into A1 and then start autofilling all cells you will need in the forseeable future. Looks kinda ugly though.

Comment: Yes, this was also my first approach. However, since I want to export this second table, I need to filter out formulas ending in errors for empty cells and then empty rows in general - as you said, really ugly... Therefore I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: Please do define what you want in the question and not in comments.

Comment: ??? This was just an example for reprocessing later on...